# How can I identify possible tonal maskers from frequency and DFT coefficients?

Tags: fft, dft, homework

I have a question given in my homework and I have no idea how to even approach it:

Given I have 5 frequencies that are inside the zone of a bark from `200-300 HZ` range  with values:
`220Hz`,`230Hz`,`240Hz`,`250Hz`,`260Hz`.

Given that the meter of their equivalent DFT coefficients are:  `1300, 1305, 2000, 100, 1000` .

Which of these frequencies are possible tonal maskers and why?

Comment: What have you learned about masking so far ? Sorry, we don't provide complete answers to homework questions.

Comment: Hilmar is absolutely right. You should at least provide some of your work and approach/thinking, let us know where, and possibly why you are stuck (what is that confuses you) and we, hopefully, will be able to provide hints. But, please keep in mind that we don’t provide homework solutions.